# android system stats in eclipse debug perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, statistics, system

How can i monitor the ram, cpu usage, running processes  of android applications from debug perspective in eclipse(with bars and graphs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the debug perspective, you can add views from other perspectives.  The Eclipse tools for Android include a host of different views that display most if not all of the things you're looking for.

To add in a new view, open the Window menu and select Show View->Other.  In the dialog that pops up, find the Android folder.  Inside you'll find these views.

Allocation Tracker/Heap views will display and help you manage memory allocations.  Windows shows the open activity windows available, sort of like a list of processes.

Once the views are opened, you can drag them around to rearrange as you see fit.

Comment: thanks Chris! I think the eclipse memory analyzer tool is also very helpful for performance monitoring